# Azure WebJob Failed with exit code -1073741818

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have deployed an Azure WebJob to an existing Azure Website using Visual Studio's very helpful 'Publish as a WebJob' menu option.

The package works fine locally, but when pushed to the cloud it doesn't even reach the first line of code (which a log statement) and I get the following message:

```
[04/25/2015 19:35:44 > 287dbc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[04/25/2015 19:35:45 > 287dbc: SYS INFO] Run script 'MyJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[04/25/2015 19:35:45 > 287dbc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[04/25/2015 19:35:45 > 287dbc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[04/25/2015 19:35:45 > 287dbc: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1073741818
```

I've also tried copying the package content manually via FTP and I get the same thing.

Has anyone ever run into this? How did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I'm running into this too from time to time (usually in bursts). `-1073741818` = `0xC0000006` = `STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR` = http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/04/9172708.aspx. According to Raymond's post, this seems to be an Azure issue (something with disk, memory, or network) but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was the supported runtime in the app.config.  This didn't work:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
```

this did:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to deploy webjob through visual studio. Steps:

1. right click on webjob project
2. publish on azure
3. select service name
4. click on publish button

I also facws same issue, if i tried to deploy webjob in azure.portal. Add your subscription in visual studio and follow the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

i run into similar one before.
it occurs cause of unhanded exceptions that is being thrown in your first lines at program.cs file. try put all your host configuration within try and catch exception and check the thrown Exception via logs.